# Error: command not found

Tags: bash

Im getting this error somehow.. still cant figure it out by myself:

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $# != 4 )); then 
    echo wrong parametrs
    echo 1
fi
if [[ ! -f $2 ]];then
    echo file 2 doesnt exist
    exit 1;
fi

$2 < $3 > $1 #line 11
if  diff $4 $1 > /dev/null; then
    echo InOut V
    exit 0
else
    echo InOut X
    exit 1
fi
```

and I try to run it like this:

```
./test file.log myecho echo.in echo.out
```

and it says: `line 11: command: myecho : not found`

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @terdon To run the program $2 with $3 as input. now if I put `./$2 < $3 > $1` it works.. why ?

Comment: Side note: Make sure to always quote variables in shell scripts (`"$1"` instead of `$1`). If you don't, the shell will split the variable content into separate tokens on whitespace, so for example filenames with spaces in them won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do here but the problem is that you are attempting to execute `myecho` as a program. Let's have a look at the relevant line:

```
$2 < $3 > $1
```

Here, `$2` is `myecho`, `$3` is `echo.in` and `$1` is `file.log`. Therefore, what you are running is:

```
myecho < echo.in > file.log
```

Based on your script's output, you have a file called `myecho` in the current directory (else the script would have complained about file 2 not existing). However, your current directory is apparently not in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Therefore, when you attempt to execute `myecho`, the system searches for an executable of that name in the directories in your `$PATH`, doesn't find one and complains.

The simplest solution is to call `./$2` instead of `$2` which tells your shell to execute the file called `myecho` in the current directory and not to search for it in those in the `$PATH`.

Alternatively, you could add your current directory to your `$PATH`. Add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
PATH="$PATH:"
```

The trailing `:` adds your current directory (whatever that may be) to your `$PATH`. You will have to log out and log back in again or manually source `.profile` (`. ~/.profile`) for the changes to take effect. Note that this can be dangerous in some cases where, for example, an attacker has uploaded a malicious executable to your current directory and named it `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

In line 11, you're running the command `$2`.
`$2` evaluates to the second argument given to the script, which is `myecho` in your case.

From the error message you can tell that your shell can't find a command named `myecho`. It might not be installed, or in the case of a custom command like this, it might be in the wrong directory (outside the ones in `$PATH`) or just not marked as executable (`chmod +x`).

Comment: Okay. Now after I changed it to `./$2 < $3 > $1` it worked just fine! explaination?

Comment: @SijaanHallak Explanation: When you try to execute a command (at your shell prompt or in a script), your shell first checks if there's a shell built-in or function with that name. If there isn't, it searches the `:`-separated directories in the `$PATH` variable for an executable file with that name and executes the first one it finds. The current directory (`.`) isn't in the `$PATH` by default, so the shell doesn't look there when searching for the command.

Comment: @SijaanHallak While your fix works for your current narrow use case, it will break when you try to use a command in a different directory as the second argument. If you want to avoid that problem, you can add `.` to `$PATH` in your script and let the shell do the searching again: `PATH=".:$PATH` (and then ditch the `./` in front of the $2).